# Dehydrator switch replacement help requested

Tags: switch

[image] The last time I tried to dry some herbs in this dehydrator, the rocker-type switch disintigrated somewhat. (Oxymoron?)
I want to replace it with either the 3-position switch shown, or a 15amp 120v light switch. Which can i use? The previous switch had a small light in it... is that the blue wire function?
And since i need this thing pretty bad, where would the red, blue and white wires be placed on the next switch? I don't want to experiment.  Thanks, Darin Wiseman ohio

Comment: Also,the blue wire is the only one not Copper.

Comment: The old switch gets line and neutral for the light to work. The middle pin is the output. You can replace it with an unlighted switch by capping off the red wire and hooking the blue and white wires to a new switch.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because small appliance repair has been deemed to be off-topic.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for allowing it to be answered.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @KMJ  appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very common switch design.

Start by searching "chassis mount rocker switch neon" then hone it down from there to the size [they come in two main widths] voltage, etc.

I can't quite read it from your picture, but there should be sufficient information on the side of that switch to get an exact match. You'll be looking for a code, SPST, SPDT etc to get the exact switch type [single/double pole, single/double throw.]

…or if you've got a Radio Shack, Tandy etc near you, take it along & ask the staff. [Make a good note of which wire went where.]
Expect to pay about $£€ 1.

Comment: Haven't been any retail Radio Shack stores in years. Ah, the good ol' days.

Comment: Ah, didn't know they'd gone too. The UK apparently still has Tandy, though our biggest 'radio ham' shop was Maplins - they went under a few years ago now. They were useful if you needed a bit you weren't quite sure about; much simpler than trying to figure out the right thing from the 2 UK 'majors', RS or Farnell's, who will have 250 similar, but distinct, products. [I did try them for this switch… urgh, minefield.]